# How do I reach my pi once I've set a static ip address

Tags: static-ip

I have followed the latest guide about changing the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file, and successfully set a static ip address, but then I can't reach the pi through ssh or a browser (it's a server).  Any body else experience this?

Comment: Can you please post a link to the guide you followed?  I set my static IP address by updating `/etc/network/interfaces`.  Can you `ping` the static IP address up configured?

Comment: Why do you have to set a static address on the RPi - why not just tell your router to assign a fixed address to the MAC associated with your RPi?

Comment: I can give you the post that took me there. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37916/setting-up-static-ip-address-on-raspian-jessie

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough yet to assign the fixed address, still learning

Answer (score 1):

As you know, networking configuration in Raspbian Jessie has moved to /etc/dhcpcd.conf .

Try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Restart networking:

> sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0

2. Check if your interface is configured:

> ifconfig

Does eth0 have the address you specified?

3. Did you format the address in /etc/dhcpcd.conf with CIDR subnet mask notation, and does the subnet mask match your local area network (/24 is equivalent to 255.255.255.0):

> static ip_address=10.0.1.59/24

?

Comment: O.k. I tried number 1 with no luck. Number 2 is a yes (I have to plug in a monitor and keyboard to access the config files.  and the address I specified in the dhcpd.conf file was : 192.168.1.1/24. On a side note,( I am not trying to correct you - I promise) I may have a newer version of jessie, but my file is named /etc/dhcpcd.  I don't have anything with the shorter name. :(

Comment: Hello, it's working.  I tried 192.168.0.201/24 instead of 192.168.1.1/24 and it worked perfectly.  I don't know why, though.  Maybe it has to do with them being on different subnets? Anywho, thank you for your help!

Comment: Apologies, you are correct, my memory failed me. Answer has beed edited.

Comment: Regarding your fix, it did not work prior because network hosts on different subnets can not reach each other without a router between.

Comment: o.k. that seems legit